# Is there a way to return the current region-based decimal and thousands separators in a shell script on macOS?

Tags: macos, shell, decimal-point

I'm wanting a way to return the current decimal and thousands separators based on the region setting. I know that you can get the language-based separators using `locale decimal_point` and `locale thousands_sep`, and if you have custom separators set you can use `defaults read -g AppleICUNumberSymbols`, but I can't find a way to return the region-based values.

For example, in the Language & Region System Preferences page, the preferred language is set to English and the Region is set to France. I want something that will return " " for the thousands separator and "," for the decimal separator.

Comment: Do you really need Shell Scripts? Do you know that there is a possibility to use Swift scripts, so you might retrieve it with that, using `Foundation.framework`?

Comment: @Larme This is for an Automator application so it doesn't strictly have to be shell. It's just that everything else in it so far is shell. I don't believe I could make use of `Foundation.framework` in an Automator application could I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so based on Larme's suggestions of Foundation.framework, I've come up with the following solution that will give me what I want in a shell script using osascript to access NSNumberFormatter:

`osascript -e 'use framework "Foundation"' -e 'return (decimalSeparator of init() of alloc() of NSNumberFormatter of current application as string)'`